# Rspec loads routes.rb twice

Tags: rspec, routes, capybara

I have a problem where Rspec loads routes twice and throws an error because of that.
I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of days with no luck. Searching the Internet doesn't lead to much. When I run rspec it's giving the following error:

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'root'  (ArgumentError)
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1445:in `add_route'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1422:in `decomposed_match'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1403:in `block in match'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1394:in `each'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1394:in `match'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:330:in `root'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1464:in `root'
from /home/user/Documents/app/config/routes.rb:21:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:341:in `instance_exec'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:341:in `eval_block'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:319:in `draw'
from /home/user/Documents/app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from /home/v/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
from /home/v/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /home/user/Documents/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/Documents/app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `require'
from /home/user/Documents/app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/Documents/app/spec/features/registration_pages_spec.rb:1:in `require'
from /home/user/Documents/app/spec/features/registration_pages_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.8/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Here's my `routes.rb` file:

```
App::Application.routes.draw do
  root 'registrations#new'
end
```

There are other things in it, but I can comment them all out and still get the error. Therefore they are not relevant.

`spec_helper.rb` :

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
#Capybara
require 'capybara/rspec'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Helpers

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.order = "random"
end
```

Part of my Gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.0'
end
```

The problem is that Rspec is trying to load routes.rb twice. I tested this by putting `puts "here"` in routes.rb file. For the love of SO I cannot figure out why, or how to possibly debug this.
When I run `rake routes` it only shows one route for root and if I comment it out in routes.rb, then it does not show. It seems like everything is correct basically, except that rspec is not working.
Also, here's a similar problem [When I use rspec: Invalid route name, already in use: 'root' (ArgumentError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473157/when-i-use-rspec-invalid-route-name-already-in-use-root-argumenterror) , however it is not the same (the OP is unclear) - I know that in my case the reason is because Rspec is loading routes twice. Please help, I'm really stuck on this one. Any suggestions would be good right now.

Comment: Having the exact same problem here. Downgrading rspec-rails to 2.x fixes it but I would rather find out what's wrong than just downgrade.

Comment: I haven't figured it out yet and I had this same problem on another project. For now I use workaround, rspec tests work if I comment out line with `root` in `routes.rb` So I've just been commenting it out to run the tests when needed.